# Quantitative property of automorphisms in finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose the automorphism $T$ sends more than three-quarters of the element of $G$ onto their inverses. Prove that $T(x)=x^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$ and that $G$ is abelian.

**Remark:** I have met this problem in some topics of this forum but all of them were about abeliniaty of $G$. Using some *hints* (not solutions!) from those topics I will provide the solution. So I would be grateful if you check it out, especially the proof that $T(x)=x^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$.

**Proof:** I. Let $A=\{x\in G: T(x)=x^{-1}\}$. Consider the set $K:=A\cap a^{-1}A$. It's easy to verify that $y\in K$ iff $ya=ay$ i.e. $y\in N(a)$. Thus $K\subset N(a)$, so $|K|\leq |N(a)|$. Since $$|K|=|A\cap a^{-1}A|=|A|+|a^{-1}A|-|A\cup a^{-1}A|>\frac{3|G|}{4}+\frac{3|G|}{4}-|G|=\frac{|G|}{2}$$
Thus, $|N(a)|> \frac{|G|}{2}$ and since $N(a)\leq G$ $\Rightarrow$ $N(a)=G$ for all $a\in A$. In other words, any element from $A$ commutes with any element from $G$. So, $A\subset Z(G)$ $\Rightarrow$ $|Z(G)|\geq |A|>\dfrac{|G|}{2}$ and $G=Z(G)$. Thus, $G$ is abelian group.

II. Let's prove that $T(x)=x^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$. Suppose that exists $x_0\in G\setminus A$ such that $T(x_0)\neq x_0$. For any $g\in A$ we have $gx_0=x_0g$ so $g^{-1}x_0^{-1}=x_0^{-1}g^{-1}$. We have: $$T(x_0g)=T(x_0)T(g)=T(x_0)g^{-1}\neq x_0^{-1}g^{-1}=g^{-1}x_0^{-1}=(x_0g)^{-1}$$
In otwer words, $x_0g\notin A$ (or $\in A^c$) for any $g\in A$. Thus, $x_0A\subset A^c$ and since $A$ is subset of finite group then $|A^c|\geq |x_0A|=|A|$ which is contradiction since $|A|>\frac{3|G|}{4}$ and $|A^c|<\frac{|G|}{4}$. This contradiction shows that $T(x)=x^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$.

Comment: What is a when it's first mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Given that the group is abelian, you can even conclude $T(x) =x^{-1}$ from the fact that now A is a (big) subgroup, so it equals G.

Comment: You mean that $A=G$? Could you show how to do it?

Comment: Taking the inverse is a homorphism in the case of abelian groups. Generally, the locus where two homomorphisms coincide is a subgroup. Thus, $A$ is a subgroup of G of cardinality greater than $|G|/2 $, i.e. is G.

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1 :)